# inserting data Xcode mysql zero

Tags: php, mysql, ios

this is how I insert

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost//Insert.php?ID=%@&date=%@&time=%@&age=%f";
```

this is in  PHP

```
   if (isset ($_GET["ID"]) && isset ($_GET["date"]) && isset ($_GET["time"]) && isset ($_GET["age"]) )
{
$ID = $_GET["ID"];
        $date = $_GET["date"];
        $time = $_GET["time"];
        $age = $_GET["age"];}
```

insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  $DB_Table VALUES ('', '".$date."', '".$time."', '".$age."')";
```

these there properties in Xcode

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *time;
@property (nonatomic) float age;
```

as i insert the data all new data gives me ZEROS although age is also float in mysql.
what could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried to NSLog the url you created in obj c?

Comment: @winya yes it gives me ID=1date=27/03/2014time=01-17age=9.000000

Comment: The & character is missing from between the parameters. It should be ID=1&date=27/03/2014&time=01-17&age=9.000000. Does your networking framework urlencode the parameters automatically?